# Dividing a frequency column

Tags: r

I am struggling with a very simple issue.  I am dealing with a year of crime data.  I simply want to divide the frequency of each type of crime by a particular number.  The dataframe is titled counts.

Right now the data the appears as such:

Column 1: Category

`Arson`
`Assault`
`Murder`

Column 2: Freq

`30`
`10`
`5`

I want to divide the frequency column by 8.15.

I have tried the following:

```
SFcrimeRate<- counts[ , 1]/8.15
```

**Error here:** `in counts[, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions`

I have also tried:

```
SFcrimeRate<- counts[Freq]/8.15
```

**Error here:** `object 'Freq' not found`
and:

```
SFcrimeRate<- counts$Freq/8.15
```

**Error here:** `$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.`

I've attempted to add margins, but this has not helped either.  Any help would be most appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: Can you [`dput` the data](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/dput.html) and paste it (or a subset of it) here?

Answer (score 0):

assuming you `freq` is in the second column of a data frame, `df`:

```
df[,2] <- df[,2]/8.15
```

For example:

```
> df <- data.frame(Crime = c("a", "b", "c"), freq = c(30, 15, 10))
> df
|Crime | freq|
|:-----|----:|
|a     |   30|
|b     |   15|
|c     |   10|
>df[,2] <- df[,2]/8.15
>df
|Crime |     freq|
|:-----|--------:|
|a     | 3.680982|
|b     | 1.840491|
|c     | 1.226994|
```